# Dgrid Locked column row height not equal in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo, dgrid

I use Dojo-1.10.4 with Dgrid-0.4.0.

If the content of a column wraps to a second line, the entire layout of the grid breaks. It works fine in Chrome, but not in IE.

I added css to sort of fix it but once a string is longer than the set row height it breaks.

You can test this with the default dgrid component:

http://dgrid.io/js/dgrid/test/complex_column.html

Comment: Include some partial/example code so that this question can be referenced later in case your link breaks.

Comment: Also it would be better to put up a screenshot and add the versions for IE for which the layout of grid breaks and the temporary fix made to solve the issue.